# How do I get two htaccess rewrite rules to 'play nice' together?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my website root I have the following to redirect to non www domain

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www\.notails\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://notails.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

in a subfolder named 'photography' I have this...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^show/([^/\.]+)/([^/]+)$ show.php?section=$1&photoid=$2 [L]
```

Anything inside the photography folder ignores the www removing rule.  How do I get these two rules to *both* apply to folders/files within the photography folder?

Also... my root htaccess file has this...

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Could it be interfering?  I have a self-hosted wordpress blog but it's not in the root of the website,  it's in a subfolder called 'blog' so I don't know why this rule is in my root's htaccess file.  Can/should I move it?

**Edit:**  Just to point out, in case it isn't obvious - I'm a complete noob when it comes to htaccess and mod_rewrite stuff.   Does a htaccess file in a subfolder override any htaccess files nearer to the root than it?  Or do the htaccess contents combine?

**Edit 2:**  I have tried moving the second rule to the same htaccess file as the www removing rule as per the following code...

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www\.notails\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://notails.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^photography/show/([^/\.]+)/([^/]+)$ photography/show.php?section=$1&photoid=$2 [L]
```

If I then go to one of my photography pages it resolves to the intended url (http://notails.com/photography/show/pointofayre/260 for example) but the page is a 404.

If I manually add 'www' to that it *undoes* the other rule... (http://notails.com/show.php?section=pointofayre&photoid=260) and removes 'photography/' from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `RewriteOptions inherit` into .htaccess in your "photography" folder because right now all rewrite rules from parent folders are ignored (default behaviour).

Alternatively move rewrite rules from that subfolder .htaccess into root one (you will need to slightly modify your rule by fixing the path -- adding `photography/` may be enough, depends on actual "photography" location)

---

**UPDATE:**
Your root .htaccess can be like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # activate rewrite engine
    RewriteEngine On
    # we are in the root
    RewriteBase /

    # no www please
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.notails\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://notails.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

    # photography
    RewriteRule ^photography/show/([^/\.]+)/([^/]+)$ /photography/show.php?section=$1&photoid=$2 [L]

    # WordPress rules
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I did try moving the rule to the root and adding 'photography/' but things got worse.  Maybe I did it wrong,  I'll try again/mess about with it.  I'll also give the inherit rule a try.

Comment: @MrVimes Show me the rule after you moved it -- maybe you have done it wrong. It also depends on how deep your "photography" folder is -- is it just ROOT/photography ? If so -- this should do the job: `RewriteRule ^photography/show/([^/\.]+)/([^/]+)$ photography/show.php?section=$1&photoid=$2 [L]`. In any case -- keep in mind that order of rules matters -- if you put it into a wrong place it may never be reached. Better post your whole .htaccess content

Comment: I made my root htaccess file like your edit.  It works until I follow a link to an individual picture (one where the second rule should kick into play) and then add www manually (to test if the first rule is still working)  it breaks - (changes 'http://notails.com/photography/show/pointofayre/260' to 'http://notails.com/show.php?section=pointofayre&photoid=260')

Comment: It looks like firefox is trolling me!  If I try the www version in firefox I get a 404.  If I try it in chrome it resolves correclty.

Comment: @MrVimes Clear your browser caches: Options | Advanced | Network -> "Clear Now" and restart Firefox.

Comment: I cleared the cache.  That worked.  So firefox was making me think a working htaccess file wasn't!  Thanks firefox! (I was even doing ctrl-f5 every time. So much for that)  Anyway,  thanks for your help @LazyOne.